# How do i remove this white thing on the side of my datagrid with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I just started getting into XAML and WPF with C# and im now using a datagrid and I have this weird white thing that I could use to resize the rows, I made it to where the user cant do it anymore but the white thing is still there. How do I get rid of it?

```
<DataGrid Name="datagridXAML" CanUserResizeRows="False" Foreground="White" RowBackground="Transparent" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="239" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505">
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvj2z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"white thing" is actually row headers. you can either set `HeadersVisibility="Column"` or `RowHeaderWidth="0"` to hide them

Comment: Amazing! That did it, I'll mark this answer as completed in 4 minutes!