# Remove row selector in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to remove selected part of data grid on this image:

[image]

I don't know what is the name of that element of data grid, but it selects whole row on click.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478034/how-do-i-remove-this-white-thing-on-the-side-of-my-datagrid-with-xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add RowHeaderWidth="0" to your DataGrid